# Passing String variable as parameter to create new Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

The title might not clarify what I'm looking for, so I'll try to explain it here.

We can create an intent to start another activity like this in Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetedActivity.class);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
String activityName = "trackingActivity.class";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityName);
startActivity(intent);
```

But this isn't working and Android Studio is giving me this error:
*"Cannot resolve Constructer ('android.content.Context, java.lang.String')"*

So, it's not accepting the 2nd parameter as string. If anyone can explain this for me that why is it happening and how it can be solved then I would be grateful.

Comment: would you please explain why you want to use `String` ?

Comment: I've 5 activities to which I'll jump from _MainActivity_ as a result of `OnClickListener`. I've a separate obj-class where I've created this `intent (this,activityName)`. And which is why I've planned to pass the `activityName` as a String from _MainActivity_ to this obj-class through set method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid passing it as `String` at first. But if its out of your control or required by your design (there is no good reason to do so), you can use `Class.forName()` for that as follows

```
    String activityName = "<packagename>.trackingActivity";
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(activityName));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //take necessary action
    }
```

Better alternatives would be as follows:

1. **Pass the Intent object**

as follows:

```
public void startActivity(final Intent intent) {
        //intent.putExtra(..)
        ...
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

2. **Pass the `Class`**

as follows:

```
public void startActivity(Class activityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
    ...
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: So, as you suggest that I should avoid passing it as a String then what is the best practice to pass this from one class to another? Kindly check my reply to @Abu Yousuf under the question.

Comment: There are two options, 1. Simply pass the `Intent` object. 2. Pass the type `class`.

Comment: I got it working by passing the Class. So, what is preferable ,, to pass the class or pass just the Intent object?

Comment: Its design choice and depends on your need. Both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Polymorphism` concept of `OOP`. Suppose you have 5 `Activity`.

`Activity1`, `Activity2`, `Activity3`, `Activity4`, `Activity5`.

Use this method

```
private Intent getActivityIntent(Class<? extends Activity> mStartActivityClass){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mStartActivityClass);
    return intent;
}
```

Then start `Activity` like:

```
Intent intent1 = getActivityIntent(Activity1.class); 
startActivity(intent1);

Intent intent2 = getActivityIntent(Activity2.class); 
startActivity(intent2);

Intent intent3 = getActivityIntent(Activity3.class); 
startActivity(intent3);

.............
```

You don't have to repeat your code . One method can handle all `Activity` class

Comment: Passing the class, yes as suggested by @Sagar! Can you please explain the use of `<? extends Activity>'? Thanks!

Comment: Learn about Generics first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html   Then Upper Bounded Wildcards https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html